# Import html-to-draftjs on Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, draftjs

I unable to import html-to-draftjs on my Nextjs Project. If I import it with:

```
import htmlToDraft from "html-to-draftjs"
```

The result will be:

[image: window is not defined]

I try to use dynamic import:

```
const htmlToDraft = dynamic(
  () => {
    return import("html-to-draftjs");
  },
  { ssr: false }
);
```

The result is:
[image: htmlToDraftjs is not a function]

**Is there any other import method that I can try? or maybe is there any alternative htmltodraft module that i can use? Thank You!**

Comment: Dynamic imports are asynchronous by nature, in your case you're only returning a promise rather than the imported module.

Comment: @SamuelHulla so, how the dynamic import should like? i mean, i do dynamic import on other module and it's worked. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window` object is not available at server. So the error happens on the server. If you only want to run `htmlToDraft` on browser then you should run it on `componentDidMount` as I can see you are using class components.

The `componentDidMount` lifecycle method only execute on client side in Next JS.

The `render` method is going to execute in both server & client. That's why you get that error. Put that into `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 6):

There's 2 other ways, if you use functional components

`1st Method:`

Downgrade your "html-to-draftjs" package to version 1.4, so you can directly import it, without using the "dyanmic" import method.

`2nd Method:`

Import the package in this way:

```
let htmlToDraft = null;
if (typeof window === 'object') {
    htmlToDraft = require('html-to-draftjs').default;
}
```

Comment: 2nd method is worked for me

Answer (score 1):

A modern syntax solution for one of the previous solutions would look like this:

```
const htmlToDraft = typeof window === 'object' && require('html-to-draftjs').default;
```